# issue with composer when deploying using Envoyer

Tags: laravel-5, forge, laravel-envoy, envoyer.io

I'm having trouble deploying my laravel app using envoyer, the error accuer in installing composer dependencies, here it is:

Generating autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
>   php artisan optimize

[RuntimeException]
  No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

it's my first time and I'm having lots of errors and don't really know how to fix them , I'd appreciate the help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate key using command  **php artisan generate:key**

As .env is not present in production so change app.php under config file to Something like below

'key' => env('APP_KEY','base64:42KCuY7E8Zc+JHrUZFyta4yspqLAjcVZeZVvymrjZBI=')

This would solve your problem.

Comment: I have used envoyer as CI for deploying laravel project. Any help feel forward to ask.

Comment: I did manage to make it work by php artisan generate:key thanks